# What would happen to my website if I don't install consent for GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) and CCPA (California Consumer Privacy Act)?

Tags: advertising, gdpr, ccpa

I really hate the consent popup on my website. It's stupid, slow and not even helping the users.

May I know what would happen if I just remove it?

Will government of EU/California sue me or block my website in their area?

Update:

I am located in China PR and Hong Kong.
My web server is located in AWS Japan.
My Hosting company is AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely nothing will happen - it us highly unlikely they could sue you (you are outside their jurisdiction) and those jurisdictions are not designed  to block the Internet - and have bigger threats to worry about.

The bigger consideration is credibility if you have lots of customers from those juridiction.

https://gdpr.eu/companies-outside-of-europe/ is useful with respect to the what the EU expects.  If you do not target people in the EU, or your org has less then 250 people and you don't  misuse the data you are probably not even in breach of the law.

Likewise, per 1798.40 of https://theccpa.org/ it is highly doubtful this would apply as it only applies to large businesses operating in California the make a significant proportion of their money from tracking people. (Its designed to prevent a recurrance if the Cambridge Analytica scandal)

Comment: AWS has a presence is both CA and EU.  Could it be forced to act to take the site down?    Would it be unwise to travel to CA and EU if you are breaking their laws?

Comment: @StevenOstermiller In theory anything is possible  but we are talking about a trivial civil matter - and the are virtually never prosecuted (Kim Dotcom is an outlier where there is $$$ at stake) - if countries were to impose their will on citizens in foreign countries no one would be able to travel or export their goods.